# VBA Access - Find early binding code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on some software, and due to bad practice by me (sorry) and a surprise update in software, the new software will be ran accross two different versions of office, which wouldn't be an issue if I had put some dependencies on certain object libraries in the references.

I plan on converting this to "late binding" in order to solve this problem, though the problem is that I have a lot of code already written, and im not 100% sure where all of the code that requires this library is.
Is there an easy way to find everything that creates a dependancy on this object library?

I know that the only object library that gets updated when the software is opened is MS word 14.0 to MS word 15.0, so I'm guessing it's only the macros i have which interact with MS word, is there an easy way to narrow this down?

Thanks for the help, 
To all those wanting to scream at for me for such a rookie mistake, I'll promise i'll do better next time,

Comment: You could remove the reference and compile the code.  That will start showing what needs updating.  Have a copy of the Word VBE open and when it highlights things like `wdWord` just type `?wdWord` into the Word Immediate window and it will show you need to replace that with the number `2`.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.
Thanks for the suggestion, worked a treat!

Comment: I might have to expand it into a full answer then.  Glad it worked.

Comment: well, it pointed me to the right places, but didn't pick up on some of the additional code changes needed. That is to said, pointed me to the modules, but some of the code needed changing, and while "not wrong" it didnt do what it should have done without some modifications